# Ordinal Numbers In Declarations (JavaScript => discord.js)

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js, ordinal

Im trying to make ordinal numbers for my welcomer, but i can't make it cause the input needs to be **integer** how do i make like making it with declarations? Yea ik it's not related to djs but i tryed this

```js
const { Client, Message } = require("discord.js");
module.exports = {
  name: "position",    
    category: 'Informations',
    aliases: [],
  /**
   * @param {Client} client
   * @param {Message} message
   */
  run: async (client, message, args) => {
    const member = message.mentions.members.first();

    if (!member) return message.reply("Please specify a member!");

    function ordinal(n) {
      var s = ["th", "st", "nd", "rd"];
      var v = n%100;
     return n + (s[(v-20)%10] || s[v] || s[0]);
    }
    const members = message.guild.members.cache
      .sort((a, b) => a.joinedTimestamp - b.joinedTimestamp)
      .array();

    const position = new Promise((ful) => {
      for (let i = 1; i < members.length + 1; i++) {
        if (members[i - 1].id === member.id) ful(i);
      }
    });

    message.channel.send(
      `${member} is the ${await ordinal(position)} member to join the server!`
    );
  },
};
```

I tryed this code but the input must me an integer, how do i make like with declarations sorry for confusing you but i need it rn

Comment: Could you please be more descriptive? I'm having trouble understanding your problem. Is there a specific line requiring your input to be an integer? If so, which line and which variable?
Also, did you know about [`isNaN()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN) function? You can easily check if your variable IS an integer, and handle the code otherwise.